# Is it bad form to ask a question in order to spark a discussion?

Tags: discussion

Especially if it isn't about a specific technology?

Comment: On the main site, yes, absolutely.  This isn't a place for discussion, although there is always chat.

Comment: @casperOne - would you consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925241/how-does-one-learn-a-new-programming-language-in-an-idiomatic-way) out-of-bounds?  If so, where would one spark such a discussion within the stackexchange community?

Comment: You have your answer, which is the exact answer I would have given if I had responded sooner.  I agree with Michael completely on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; there's a close reason dedicated to it:

> ###not constructive
> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, [see the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) for guidance.

If you really want to have a discussion, [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) is probably the best place

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll go nuke the question, if I can.

Comment: FYI, I answered my own question and voted to have it closed.  Geek sepuku?

Comment: which stackexchange chat would you suggest that explore?